# Open frame from button

Tags: python, tkinter

I have this code which open a frame, count 5 seconds and then open another frame. Here i have some buttons that should open different frames but they all open same second frame that is already opened by counter.

I don t get it why is this happen.
Any idea or help?

```
import tkMessageBox
import MySQLdb
import sys
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import time
import calendar
import struct
import traceback
import uuid
import random
import hashlib
import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import *
from functools import partial
import ttk

LARGE_FONT= ("Verdana", 12)

start_app = time.time()

class ChangePages(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack()
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frames = {}

        for F in (PageSTART,PageSELECT,PageZS,PageARH,PageSET,PageHLP):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(PageSTART)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class PageSTART(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        self.control=controller
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        f = Frame(self)
        f.pack(side='left')

        self.initializaresenz=Label(f,text='',font=("Arial", 18, "bold"),fg='#ff9900',width=35,height=3)
        self.initializaresenz.grid(row=4,column=0,columnspan=6)

        self.initializarestatus1=Label(f,text='Start!',font=("Arial", 18, "bold"),fg='#00cc33',width=55,height=3)
        self.initializarestatus1.grid(row=5,column=0,columnspan=6)
        self.initializarestatus2=Label(f,text='Error!',font=("Arial", 18, "bold"),fg='#ff3300',width=55,height=3)
        self.initializarestatus2.grid(row=5,column=0,columnspan=6)
        self.initializarestatus1.grid_remove()
        self.initializarestatus2.grid_remove()

        self.update_labels()

    def update_labels(self):

        now=time.time()
        diff =15 - int(now-start_app)
        txt_diff = ''

        if diff < 0:
            diff = '00'

        if diff < 10:
            txt_diff='0'+str(diff)
        else:
            txt_diff=str(diff)

        if diff < 9:
            self.initializarestatus1.grid()
            self.initializarestatus2.grid_remove()
            self.control.show_frame(PageSELECT)

        elif diff < 1:
            self.initializarestatus2.grid()
            self.initializarestatus1.grid_remove()

        self.initializaresenz.configure(text='Counting ... ' + txt_diff)

        self.after(10, self.update_labels)

class PageSELECT(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        f = Frame(self)
        f.pack(side='left')

        btnarh=Button(f,text='ARH',fg='blue',font=('Helvetica',18),height=1, width=10,command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageZS))
        btnarh.grid(row=1,column=0)
        btnset=Button(f,text='SET',fg='blue',font=('Helvetica',18),height=1, width=10,command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageSET))
        btnset.grid(row=1,column=1)
        btnhlp=Button(f,text='HLP',fg='blue',font=('Helvetica',18),height=1, width=10,command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageHLP))
        btnhlp.grid(row=2,column=0)
        btnex=Button(f,text='EXIT',fg='blue',font=('Helvetica',18),height=1, width=10,command=self.exit)
        btnex.grid(row=2,column=1)

    def exit(self):
        mExit = tkMessageBox.askyesno(title='Exit', message='Exit ?')
        if mExit > 0:
            app.destroy()
            return

class PageZS(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        f = Frame(self)
        f.pack(side='left')

        labelspacing=Label(f,text='Page ZS',font=("Arial", 12, "bold"),width=35,height=0,relief='groove').grid(row=0,column=4)

class PageARH(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        f = Frame(self)
        f.pack(side='left')

        labelspacing=Label(f,text='Page ARH',font=("Arial", 18, "bold"),width=9,height=1).grid(row=0,column=0)

class PageSET(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        f = Frame(self)
        f.pack(side='left')

        labelspacing=Label(f,text='Page SET',font=("Arial", 18, "bold"),width=9,height=1).grid(row=0,column=0)


class PageHLP(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        f = Frame(self)
        f.pack(side='left')

        labelspacing=Label(f,text='Page HLP',font=("Arial", 18, "bold"),width=9,height=1).grid(row=0,column=0)


#Root loop
app = ChangePages()
app.geometry('600x400+0+0')
app.title('ASV Technologies ')
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is easier without the inheritance, which seems to be the confusing part in the above program.  You simply pass the parent/root window that you want to use.  It may be easier to understand by calling a function in the master program from the button press, and using the function to call the class.  You can also save the class instance when calling it from a function, if you want to access the second class from the calling class.  This program calls one additional class many times, but calling different classes using different buttons should be an easy extension.

```
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    import Tkinter as tk     ## Python 2.x
else:
    import tkinter as tk     ## Python 3.x

from functools import partial

class OpenToplevels():
    """ open and close additional Toplevels with a button
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        but=tk.Button(self.root, text="Open a Toplevel",
                      command=partial(Another, self.root))
        but.grid(row=0, column=0)
        tk.Button(self.root, text="Exit Tkinter", bg="red",
                  command=self.root.quit).grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="we")
        self.root.mainloop()

class Another():
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent=parent
        self.open_another()

    def close_it(self):
        self.id.destroy()

    def open_another(self):
        ## open a Toplevel as it is more visible as an example
        self.id = tk.Toplevel(self.parent)
        ## put something in the Toplevel
        tk.Button(self.id, text="Close Toplevel",
                  command=self.close_it,
                  bg="orange").grid(row=1, column=0)

Ot=OpenToplevels()
```

Comment: Is that possible to fix my code also? I really appreciate your answer and keep it in mind but i would like to make my code working in the way i have it. Thanks a lot